# Functions f,g are both Real-Analytic in (a,b) and $f^{(n)}(x)=g^{(n)}(x)$ for some x in (a,b). Does it imply f=g?

Tags: real-analysis

Here $f^{(n)}(x)$ stands for the $n$-th derivative EDIT and $n=0,1,2,...$ with $f^{(0)}(x)$ defined as $f(x)$ .This is what I have so far : the set S where $ f \neq g $ is open in $(a,b)$ as

$S$={$x: f(x)>g(x) $} $\cup $ {$x:f(x)-g(x)$} respectively. Set $h:=f-g$ , then these two sets are respectively equivalent to: $h^{-1}(0, \infty) \cup h^{-1}( - \infty, 0)$ , so $S$ is open in $(a,b)$ and its complement $S^{c}$ is closed in $(a,b)$, so they cannot be equal everywhere, since then $(a,b)$ would be clopen. Can we conclude at least that $f=g$ in a neighborhood of $x$ ? Or maybe $(a,b)$ can be clopen while being connected, since , as a subspace, it is the whole space?

Also, does  $f^{(n)}(x)=g^{(n)}(x)$ imply that the two Taylor series are identical? Or is it possible for the two to be identical value-wise without being equal as formulas? I am thinking of Complex-analytic functions which can be equal to each other in a discrete subset of the Complex plane without being equal throughout the plane (EDIT: Or in the region where they are both defined) by the Identity Theorem. But I can't make the leap to Real-analytic ones.

Comment: You mean $f^{(n)}(x)=g^{(n)}(x)$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: @Mesmerizedstudent: I mean for n=0,1,2,... ; not sure if you include 0 in $\mathbb N$ ; some don't.

Comment: @Mesmerizedstudent: Just edited to specify, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Unless I'm missing out something, I think $h(x+\varepsilon)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} h^{(n)}(x) \varepsilon^n = 0$ for $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small.

Comment: @LeoMito: Could be. But if h was Complex-analytic, then that would not hold, as the zeros of a non-zero Complex-Analytic function are isolated. And every Real-Analytic function is the Real/Complex part of a Complex-analytic function, so I am not 100% .

Comment: If I remember well from Differential equation course -  we have only one analytic function defined in neighborhood of $x$ with given values of derivatives. So $f=g$ in this neighborhood.

Comment: @Mesmerizedstudent: But what if you add a constant to the function? Then the derivatives would all be equal. Unless you include the value of the function. Or you mean equality up to a constant?

Comment: You have to include, if we are talking about the Cauchy-Kovalevskaya theorem.

Comment: Ok, thanks, will look it up.

Comment: A standard argument for this problem is to show that $T=\cap_{n=0}^{\infty} \{ x\in (a,b) | f^{(n)}(x)= g^{(n)}(x)\}$ is both open and closed in $(a,b)$.

Comment: Series are identical so are functions ... this works for both complex and real functions

Comment: Agree with i707107's suggestion. $T$ clearly closed. If $y\in T$, then the two Taylor series centered at $y$ agree, so by real analyticity there is a neighborhood of $y$ contained in $T$, so $T$ is also open.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Yes, but what confuses me is that it seems Complex-analytic functions f,g  can agree in many points without being identical, so that  f-g can be identically zero in isolated points.

Comment: MSIS, IIRC if two complex analytic functions agree on a set that contains an accumulation point of itself, then they are equal. The same is happening here.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: But by assumption they agree only at one point. The set of agreement is clearly closed , seeing it as {$ h^{-1}(0)$} where $h:f-g$, but the problem would be proving it is also open in $(a,b)$. I don't see how it is clear that $f,g$ agree on a set with a limit point in $(a,b)$. This is what we are trying to prove, isn't it?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Dont $f=e^x -1$ and $g=0$ , both analytic in the Real line agree in just one point ( so we do not have the open condition)?

Comment: MSIS The condition for the set $T$ was that **all** the derivatives also agree at the point. IOW $f^{(n)}(x)=g^{(n)}(x)$ for all $n\in\Bbb{N}_0$. That doesn't hold with your $f$ and $g$.